How to compute this Limit involving an Exponential Integral (Solved using Clever methods)
I was trying to calculate the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}2\text{Ei}(-x)-2\text{Ei}(-2x)$$ and I had absolutely no idea how to do it and how it simplifies to: $$-\ln4$$ This was for the bounds of an Definite Integral from $0$ to $\infty$, calculating the limit to infinity was easy, but for $0$ I find it much harder.
Edit: Here is the integral which I was trying to calculate: $$F(x)=\int(\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x})^{2}dx=\frac{2e^{-x}-e^{-2x}-1}{x}+2\text{Ei}(-x)-2\text{Ei}(-2x)$$ I just needed to compute this:$$I=\lim_{x \to \infty}F(x)-\lim_{x \to 0}F(x)=0-\lim_{x \to 0} F(x)$$
Edit 2: To clear confusion: $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2e^{-x}-e^{-2x}-1}{x} =0$$ I already knew about this part, the main part is the Ei(x) function here.
Edit 3: Here is the Taylor Series answer which the other user had also talked about, we need to first figure out the Taylor Series of Ei(x) which can't be easily found online (apparently), so here is the derivation: $$\int_{}^{}\frac{e^{x}}{x}dx=c+\ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{(n)(n!)}$$ Now we can substitute the original functions with this definition. $$\lim_{x\to0}2\text{Ei}(-x)-2\text{Ei}(-2x)=\lim_{x\to0}2\ln(-x)+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{n}}{(n)(n!)}-2\ln(-2x)-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-2x)^{n}}{(n)(n!)}=\lim_{x\to0}2\ln(-x)-2\ln(-2x)=\lim_{x\to0}-2\ln2=-\ln4$$

Added the whole question, also side note, I think there is an easier way to actually solve the definite integral, but I'm still looking for how to compute that limit.

rewriting the limit using the definition of $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$ and using the Taylor expansion of $e^{-t}$ near $0$ should do the job

you don't need the full serie expansion of $e^{-t}$. As I wrote in my answer, $e^{-t}=1-t+o(t)$, so when you integrate $\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^{-t}}tdt$, the error goes to $0$.  $\int_x^{2x} \frac{1-t}tdt=\log(2)-x\to \log 2$ and so on for the other terms of the expansion. Hence, the limit approaches $\log 2$

The limit is equivalent to $2\lim_{x\to 0} (\operatorname{Ei}(-x)-\operatorname{Ei}(-2x))$ where
$$\operatorname{Ei}(x):=- \int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^{t}}{t}\mathrm dt$$
If $x\to 0^+$:
\begin{align}\operatorname{Ei}(-x)-\operatorname{Ei}(-2x)=- \int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt + \int_{2x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt=-\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt\end{align}
using $e^{-t}=1-t+o(t)$ you have:
$$\int_x^{2x}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\mathrm dt\sim \int_x^{2x}\frac1t \mathrm dt=\log 2 \quad\text{as} \quad x\to 0^+  $$
Using the same procedure, you evaluate the limit as $x\to 0^-$. Hence the limit is $-\log 4$.

Thank you, your original answer of using a Taylor Series also worked really well for me and I also think that it's slightly easier and less complicated.
